# What does Google do with existing indexed HTTP links when a domain is updated to use HTTPS (SSL) ~

Tags: ssl, web, seo

This one has me boggled, can't seem to find any answers.

I recently went ahead with an SSL license for my domain and as such, now use site-wide HTTPS. 
I've set up a rewrite rule that 301 redirects any persons coming from a HTTP link to the new version. All of this is working fine.

My question is... what happens now in regards to Google rankings? The original site is up there (Ie, www.domain.com) albeit using HTTP, though clicking the link fixes that obviously. 
Except Googlebot is evidently unable to crawl this version now because it reads the redirect.

Since Google is unable to crawl (and I'm assuming other search engines also), will this swiftly descend into oblivion in terms of search rankings? Will it simply update next-crawl to use the HTTPS. Or, the route I'm currently taking, will I need to start over by setting up the HTTPS version in Webmaster Tools and change as many external links elsewhere as I can?

Where would I stand taking this route if I could no longer fund the SSL license and had to revert back? Same process?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is about SEO

Comment: Not necessarily. I also need to know if changing all internal links to HTTPS is a wise idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 301 redirect will tell Google your URLs have changed and to associate the old URLs with the New URLs (and to carry over all of the link juice, etc). It will take some time for Google to get caught up with the changes and as with any significant change you may see (significant) fluctuations in your pages' rankings. However, this is normal and you should not change anything.

If you change back to non-SSL pages the same process would apply.

Comment: More info from a Google-controlled source: [https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en)

Comment: Spot on what I needed to know. Thank you very much!